# Optimize for-loop in pandas for calculating distances and speed of a dataframe consisting of coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a code snippet that discretizes coordinates in a DataFrame to a specific line length and assigns speed values based on the line length between consecutive points. While the code works, it seems to be inefficient and I would like to optimize it for better performance. First, here is a short example of how the dataframe looks like:

```
# Create a time range
time_range = pd.date_range('2023-07-11 00:00:00', periods=10, freq='5S')

# Generate random x and y coordinates
x_coordinates = np.random.rand(10)
y_coordinates = np.random.rand(10)

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x_coordinates, 'y': y_coordinates}, index=time_range)
```

part of the output :

```
                            x         y
2023-07-11 00:00:00  0.529496  0.237321
2023-07-11 00:00:05  0.745546  0.351738
2023-07-11 00:00:10  0.146295  0.982289
2023-07-11 00:00:15  0.732974  0.526501
2023-07-11 00:00:20  0.713234  0.377941
2023-07-11 00:00:25  0.099409  0.630578
```

My goal is to iterate over the time steps, and as soon as the distance from the previous and current coordinates is bigger than a certain threshold, extract this position, calculate the speed and append it an array, which will be needed for plotting later. Here is how I managed to solve this, but highly inefficient I suppose:

```
# the original dataframe has more columns, than just 'x' and 'y', thus I select it here 
# explicitly, moreover I create the speed column, where I calculate the speed later
df = df[['x', 'y']]
df = df.assign(speed=np.repeat(0, len(df)))

# Discretize the points according to the line length if desired
if line_length > 0:

    start_ts = df.index[0]
    start_pos = df.loc[start_ts, ['x', 'y']]
    
    # I transform the dataframe to a numpy array, because I need the data as a np.array
    # for plotting a line collection
    discretized_df = [df.loc[start_ts].to_numpy()]

    for i in range(len(df) - 1):
        end_ts = df.index[i]
        end_pos = df.loc[end_ts, ['x', 'y']]

        if np.linalg.norm(end_pos - start_pos) >= line_length:
            time_delta = (end_ts - start_ts).microseconds / 1000000
            speed = np.linalg.norm(end_pos - start_pos) / time_delta
            df.loc[end_ts, 'speed'] = speed
            discretized_df.append(df.loc[end_ts].to_numpy())
            start_ts = end_ts

    # I always want to include the last point
    df.loc[df.index[-1], 'speed'] = 0
    discretized_df.append(df.iloc[-1].to_numpy())

# the stacking is just reshaping for the line collection 
discretized_df = np.stack(discretized_df, 0)
```

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve  and I appreciate any help on how to improve this!

Comment: what is `line_length`? and `['gantry pos', 'trolley pos']`?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to rename this. The line length is the threshold that two coordinates have to exceed in order to be plotted as a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  It calculates the distances before the for loop using the vectorized method.

Note: since you didn't specify a value for `line_length` I used 1.

```
df[['dx', 'dy']] = df[['x', 'y']] - df[['x', 'y']].shift(1)
df['dist'] = np.linalg.norm(df[['dx', 'dy']], axis=1)
df['cum_dist'] = df['dist'].cumsum()

line_length = 1
dist_prev = 0
ts_prev = df.index[0]
resampled_pts = [{'Time': ts_prev, 'x': df.iloc[0]['x'], 'y': df.iloc[0]['y']}]
speeds = []
for ts, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    if (row['cum_dist'] - dist_prev) < line_length:
        continue
    resampled_pts.append({
        'Time': ts, 
        'x': row['x'],
        'y': row['y']
    })
    speeds.append({
        'Time': ts,
        'Speed': (row['cum_dist'] - dist_prev) / (ts - ts_prev).total_seconds()
    })
    ts_prev = ts
    dist_prev = row['cum_dist']

resampled_pts = pd.DataFrame.from_records(resampled_pts).set_index('Time')
speeds = pd.DataFrame.from_records(speeds).set_index('Time')

print(df)
print(resampled_pts)
print(speeds)
```

Output:

```
                            x         y        dx        dy      dist  cum_dist
2023-07-11 00:00:00  0.726821  0.218366       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2023-07-11 00:00:05  0.649865  0.030703 -0.076956 -0.187663  0.202829  0.202829
2023-07-11 00:00:10  0.104377  0.620235 -0.545488  0.589531  0.803184  1.006013
2023-07-11 00:00:15  0.649527  0.628917  0.545150  0.008682  0.545219  1.551232
2023-07-11 00:00:20  0.897746  0.931917  0.248218  0.303000  0.391690  1.942923
2023-07-11 00:00:25  0.325597  0.847569 -0.572149 -0.084348  0.578333  2.521255
2023-07-11 00:00:30  0.149648  0.785716 -0.175949 -0.061853  0.186504  2.707760
2023-07-11 00:00:35  0.452338  0.864169  0.302690  0.078452  0.312692  3.020451
2023-07-11 00:00:40  0.865927  0.375195  0.413589 -0.488973  0.640430  3.660881
2023-07-11 00:00:45  0.430665  0.259064 -0.435262 -0.116131  0.450488  4.111369
                            x         y
Time                                   
2023-07-11 00:00:00  0.726821  0.218366
2023-07-11 00:00:10  0.104377  0.620235
2023-07-11 00:00:25  0.325597  0.847569
2023-07-11 00:00:40  0.865927  0.375195
                        Speed
Time                         
2023-07-11 00:00:10  0.100601
2023-07-11 00:00:25  0.101016
2023-07-11 00:00:40  0.075975
```

Also, note that in your code you use `(end_ts - start_ts).microseconds`. The microseconds method does not return the total duration in microseconds.  It returns the microseconds residual of the time-delta.  Use `(end_ts - start_ts).total_seconds * 1000` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and tips! However, you said that I would be using `df.append`, however, I am using a python list and append the rows from the dataframe (I use `to_numpy()` before aswell). Is this still inefficient?

Comment: Ah.  Sorry, I was wrong.  I will delete that comment.  The `np.stack` of a list of arrays is quite efficient I think.